ERROR INSTALLING ZABBIX PROXY 4.4
I am trying to install a zabbix proxy 4.4 using the installation manual:
commands used for installation:
#wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.4/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_4.4-1+bionic_all.deb 
#dpkg -i zabbix-release_4.4-1+bionic_all.deb 
#apt update 

Commands used for configure MySQL and BBDD:
#sudo apt -y install zabbix-proxy-mysql 
#sudo mysql_secure_installation   
#sudo mysql –uroot –p 

create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin; 
#CREATE USER ‘zabbix’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘Yu9zz’; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON zabbix.* TO ‘zabbix’@’localhost’; 
CREATE USER ‘zabbix’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘Yu9zz’; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON zabbix.* TO ‘zabbix’@’localhost’; 
#grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by 'Yu9zz'; 

quit; 

zcat /usr/share/zabbix-proxy-mysql/schema.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix_proxy 
openssl rand -hex 32 
nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk   (copy WPA previously generated) 
chown zabbix:zabbix /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk 
chmod 644 /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk 

Editing: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.conf
DBPassword=Yu9zz (or the used password) 
ConfigFrequency=100 
Server=dnsaddressofmyzabbixserverwhereiamaddingtheproxy
Hostname=monitoringproxyclientname
ServerPort=10051 
ListenPort=10056 
StartPollers=5 
StartVMwareCollectors=5 
VMwareCacheSize=512M 
TLSConnect=psk 
TLSAccept=psk 
TLSPSKIdentity=ZBX
TLSPSKFile=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_proxy.psk 

The name of the Database that I want to use is zabbix.
The problem is that once I finish everything that is on the installation manual I get the following error saying that the zabbix database is not a zabbix database:



zcat /usr/share/zabbix-proxy-mysql/schema.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix -p zabbix_proxy


The name of the Database that I want to use is zabbix.

The DB name you specify when you import schema is not zabbix, but zabbix_proxy.
This means zabbix is an empty DB.
